# Live-Action kids sci-fi TV Show or movie from 90s/00s?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I don't remember much of this show when it comes to story aspects, but I remember the characters. One was a boy with a purple or blue t-shirt who had a metal/cybernetic headpiece and a robotic arm, another was a fuzzy blue creature with an almost Greedo-like face, and there was a dark green fish-like alien who was short and grumpy. Any ideas what I could be remembering? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps Hypernauts (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypernauts)..?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like [Galidor: Defenders of the Outer Dimension](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0310457/).

The show was accompanied by a [LEGO toy line](https://brickset.com/sets/theme-Galidor).

Comment: Any other details you can add? You can get better insight on how to write a good answer [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9444/how-to-write-a-good-story-id-answer)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Thanks for helping out and contributing an answer! But this answer could be improved even more by including some more details, such as a.) a plot summary b.) a description of how exactly it matches what the asker is looking for, and c) a description of how this question led you to this answer - did you remember it off of the top of your head? Did you search? If so, what exactly did you search for? You can also [see some advice on writing a Story-ID answer here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9445/33591) :). See you around!