# Early 2000's live action show about teenager who gets sent to a futuristic dystopian-type world and gets a robotic arm

Tags: story-identification, tv, cyborg

This one is really vague, I know. I'll try to describe it the best I can.

It was a show airing in the early 2000s. A (either Canadian/American/English) male teenager (16+, I believe) gets teleported to another world by a group of semi-deformed (their arms were quite... vainy I think) cultist-like people.

Somewhere along the way, he loses his left arm and it gets replaced by a robotic arm which has the ability to extend IIRC. The world he is on is kind of dark, desolate, 1986 *Labyrinth*-style planet. The story revolves around the teenager trying to make his way back to Earth.

One specific part of the show I remember is where he's on a train-like transport, on to top of it (typical cliche style) and he uses the robotic arm to go from carriage to carriage.

I think this was a show airing on either CITV or CBBC, though it could have even been channel 5. I remember it was accessible by early 2000's freeview.

Answer (score 2):

*Galidor: Defenders of the Outer Dimension* (2002)?

From [Brickipedia](https://brickipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Galidor):

> *Galidor - Defenders of the Outer Dimension* followed the adventures of Nicholas Bluetooth and his friend Allegra Zane, two teenagers who find themselves warped to Galidor, a world in the Outer Dimension which is being threatened by the evil Gorm. Nick and Allegra were brought there by the robot Jens, who sent a transdimensional pod to Earth to retrieve the prince of Galidor, hidden away from Gorm until he would be old enough to fight him. Once on Galidor, Nick discovers that he has the power to "glinch" - alter his limbs to copy those of anybody he meets, gaining any special abilities they have in the process, such as extendable claws or a powerful jump.

You can see his extendable robotic arm in the intro:

---

Found by browsing this site for `[story-identification] "robotic arm"` which brought up, among others, [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/173744) mentioning:

> One was a boy with a purple or blue t-shirt who had a metal/cybernetic headpiece and a robotic arm

*Galidor* was suggested as an answer (but never confirmed).

Comment: If this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the chekmark on the left.

Comment: Exactly my thought when I saw the question. If so, it's a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/129910/23243

Comment: @FuzzyBoots if the querent confirms, I suggest we dupe-close the other way: the newer question had more details. Or maybe make [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/132906/98028) the canon dupe-target. But the current one is kind of terse

Comment: Agreed. But I'm hardly an impartial party since that other one you linked is mine. I think they had a stronger "oldest one first" policy back then, or maybe I just didn't feel confident in it.